# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest warning and <script>

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting a warning message:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

when performing an asynchronous AJAX request that contains a script (that has local `src`), which is injected into HTML, using `$.html()` method. I've changed the given script to contain `async="async"`, yet the warning message still remains.

I've started debugging the issue to discover that my appended `<script>` is handled via jquery AJAX call from `jQuery.ajaxTransport` (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js, #8663), where `async` is set to `false` (that's probably where the issue comes from).

Now - what can I do about this?

The message appears in newest version of Chrome as well as Firefox.

---

While I cannot provide a test case on jsfiddle, here's a test case that displays the issue:

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/response.html',
        success: function(response){
            $(document.body).html(response);
        }
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

response.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/json.js" async="async"></script>
```

json.js

```
console.log('hi');
```

---

AJAX request is not necessary to trigger the warning - all is needed is inserting a `<script>`

test2.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).html('<script type="text/javascript" src="/json.js" async="async"><\/script>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

It's worth noting that this has been fixed, per https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2060

Comment: Some similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27736186/4043409).

Comment: Hi, could you tell me on whatsapp version of chrome and Firefox were you seeing this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** <strike>This has been fixed in jQuery 3.x.</strike> If you have no possibility to upgrade to any version above 3.0, you could use
>   following snippet BUT be aware that now you will lose sync behaviour of
>   script loading in the targeted content.

You could fix it, setting explicitly async option of xhr request to `true`:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, original_Options, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that even though this will indeed retrieve <scripts> asynchronously, it may lead to unexpected behavior since the script is loaded after the HTML containing it so if the HTML contains a call to a function declared inside the external file it might not work. This happened to me yesterday

Comment: I am using AngularJs and getting the same error , i am not sure what it is using inside , but i am just using $http for get and post requests .

Comment: How can I used with Shiny in R?

Comment: Got `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajaxPrefilter is not a function` :/

Answer (score 12):

Browsers now warn for the use of synchronous XHR. MDN says this was implemented recently:

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Here's how the change got implemented in Firefox and Chromium:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=969671
- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=184788

As for Chrome people report this started happening somewhere around version 39. I'm not sure how to link a revision/changeset to a particular version of Chrome.

Yes, it happens when jQuery appends markup to the page including script tags that load external js files. You can reproduce it with something like this:

```
$('body').append('<script src="foo.js"></script>');
```

I guess jQuery will fix this in some future version. Until then we can either ignore it or use A. Wolff's suggestion above.

Comment: Seems like a good suggestion to `$('body').append(...)`. If this is at the top of a `$(document).ready(...)` then it should provide proper readiness to execute any functions in the source script.

Comment: Another good option is to use plain JavaScript instead of jQuery to append your <script> to body. @surinder-singh posted a decent working solution to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Even the [latest jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js) has that line, so you have these options:

- Change the source of jQuery yourself - but maybe there is a good reason for its usage
- Live with the warning, please note that this option is *deprecated* and not *obsolete*.
- Change your code, so it does not use this function

I think number 2 is the most sensible course of action in this case.

By the way if you haven't already tried, try this out: `$.ajaxSetup({async:true});`, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: It won't, as `_evalUrl` specifies `async` setting explicitly.

Comment: True, however if, for some reason, jquery loads `<script>` via ajax (why?), and `async` parameter is not picked up, it would be good to fix it. Same happens with the version you've linked, so I guess it's some kind of bug, yet I wanted to make sure before submitting.

Answer (score 5):

I was plagued by this error message despite using async: true. It turns out the actual problem was using the `success` method. I changed this to `done` and warning is gone.

`success: function(response) { ... }`

replaced with:

`done: function(response) { ... }`

Comment: I didn't change anything for you, either.

Comment: Perhaps you're having an unrelated issue then.

Answer (score 5):

if you just need to load script dont do as bellow

```
$(document.body).html('<script type="text/javascript" src="/json.js" async="async"><\/script>');
```

**Try this**

```
var scriptEl = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptEl.src = "/module/script/form?_t="+(new Date()).getTime();
    //$('#holder').append(scriptEl) // <--- create warning
    document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

Comment: This effectively disables caching of JS scripts - however, if you'll remove the `getTime()` bit, then yes, it will work (as it won't use jQuery and won't be parsed, thus not going into bugged bit)

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused by the **flexie** script which was part of the "CDNJS Selections" app offered by **Cloudflare**.

According to Cloudflare "This app is being deprecated in March 2015". I turned it off and the message disappeared instantly.

You can access the apps by visiting https://www.cloudflare.com/a/cloudflare-apps/yourdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case if i append script tag like this :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'url/test.js';
$('head').append($(script));
```

i get that warning but if i append script tag to head first then change src warning gone !

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
$('head').append($(script));
script.src = 'url/test.js';
```

works fine!!