# Performance Issue causing due to "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated"

Tags: jquery, performance, asynchronous, synchronous

I am getting this warning (**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**) while sending request through ajax.
Jquery is working fine but this warning causing a performance issue in my website.

**Jquery Code**

```
$.ajax({

    url: "www.testproject.com/doubt-solving", 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result){
    $('#my-content-div').css('text-align','none');            
    $("#my-content-div").html(result.html);
}});
```

Comment: Are you setting globally all ajax requests to synchronous mode or what? Is adding option `async: true,` or `global: false,` fixing your issue? Maybe your issue comes from content you are adding from `result.html`, see e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script/28323156#28323156

Comment: Are you really sure it is the *warning* that's causing the performance issue ("this warning causing a performance issue") or would you consider that it might be the fact that you're using Synchronous XMLHttpRequests (intentionally or not / directly or not)?  The warning is there *because* Synchronous XMLHttpRequests can cause performance issues.

Comment: This has solved my bbig problem
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});