# Multiple Ajax calls appear to be treated as synchronous requests when they should not be

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request which changes the content of an input field on success.  That input field triggers another series of Ajax requests on change.  The code works, but according to the console in Chrome, it is reported that "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience".  It appears this error message indicates that synchronous requests are being made.

Here is the code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/widgets/test',
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#widgetData").val(JSON.stringify(response));
            $("#widgetData").trigger("change");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("There was a problem requesting the widget endpoint!");
        }
    });

    $("#widgetData").change(function () {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON($("#widgetData").val());
        $.each(obj, function (id, url) {
            $("#mainContent").append("<div class='widget' id='widget" + id + "'></div>");
            $("#widget" + id).load(url);
        });
    });
```

I intend all of the requests to be asynchronous and believe that what I have written should accomplish that task.  Please help me determine what is wrong, and why I am getting the aforementioned error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous XMLHttpRequest warning and <script>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script)

Comment: Thanks, @Manish, but I did already try explicitly setting "async: true" and continue to experience the issue.

Comment: is it the $.ajax call or a $.load that is triggering the warning?

Comment: The load, I'm fairly certain.  If I eliminate the load call, there's no error.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code? Not something else triggering the warning? I've created a jsfiddle which mimics your code, and it does not give any problems: https://jsfiddle.net/3scmc3db/

Comment: @Justus - With a little more searching, I think the synchronous call may be coming from one of the URLs contained in the first JSON response.  I also created a fiddle of this - http://jsfiddle.net/kr9oum3r/ - and realized that upon placing the dummy URLs into my original, the error disappeared.  I can only presume the synchronous request messing everything up must be contained on one of the load URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your first `ajax` request is setting `async` flag to `false`. You can change that call to following

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true, 
        url: '/widgets/test',
        success: function (response) {
            $("#widgetData").val(JSON.stringify(response));
            $("#widgetData").trigger("change");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("There was a problem requesting the widget endpoint!");
        }
    });
```

This should fix your warning message

Comment: async is true by default, so *"first ajax request is setting async flag to false"* is just a random guess