# jQuery action when .load() is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am trying to have an action that starts when my `load()` request is done, but the `alert` never shows up. The `load()` request works since I can see the content of `mypage.html` in my `.haha` div. This is the really simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Hello
<div class="haha"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.haha').load('mypage.html', function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
                alert('TEST TEST'); 
            }
            alert('TEST TEST'); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

None of the alerts shows up.

EDIT : 
In my console i have this :

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
FAToolbar.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

Comment: why you're checking the xhr status?

Comment: Well, with the XHR status it's supposed to tell me when my request is done and ready. But nevertheless, with or whitout it, it doesnt work

Comment: you don't need to check it. adding function at the end it will works. remove the if, and the function vars. **$('.haha').load('mypage.html', function() {alert('TEST TEST')});**

Comment: I tried that in the begining. I went looking for that xhr condition because it didn't work with your sugestion. Here's the website : http://corleonesi.forumactif.org/h3-foufou

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script

Comment: I don't have the error message in my console anymore, but i still don't see the alerts.

Comment: have you tried without the if statement?

Comment: Another stuff, use the last version of jQuery http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: call jquery just one time on your page, you're calling it two times

Comment: just another little think: **you sre loading the same page in a div which is in it**  $('.haha').load('/g3-testeurs',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you'll see that the `xhr` object is the third parameter passed to the callback function. Your code is most likely generating a syntax error in trying to access properties of the returned string which don't exist, which is stopping further execution. Try this:

```
$('.haha').load('mypage.html', function(response, status, xhr) { // note the extra params
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
        alert('TEST TEST'); 
    }
    alert('TEST TEST'); 
});
```

Comment: Oke so i tried it : http://corleonesi.forumactif.org/h3-foufou (sorry i can't do a jsfiddle because of the load()) 
It still doesn't show the alerts

Comment: In my console, i have that : 
" Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
FAToolbar.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function "

Comment: The first is a warning, not an error, and is because you've set `async: false` somewhere in your code - I strongly suggest you remove it. The second error is because you haven't included the jQuery cookie plugin before attempting to use it. Neither of these errors are related to the code you've shown in your question though.

Comment: I can see you're still getting the `$.cookie` error though.

Comment: It's oke ! I found a CDN ! for the cookie plugin ! It show the alerts now.

Comment: Well, now my page is blank but i'm gonna look what the new problem is :) SO MUCH THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

first,the function load 's callback parameter is only called after request has completed, so you don't have to check `xhr.readyState == 4`.
second,you load a html via the function `load`,and i guess that the page `mypage.html` include some javascript code , and some code call the function `$.cookie` which is not include in the page.So the error print in you console product by you js code from the page `mypage.html`.