# Load page trought AJAX, get file from location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash, get

When i try to do this:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: location.hash,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

I get this error:
*Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.*

My url is: localhost/index.php#test.php

It should use test.php as url to load.

What i need is when there is a hash in the url, i need to load the hash (filename)..

Edit:

When i add:

```
async: false,
```

I still get the same error..

Edit:

I am using jQuery version 2.1.3

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest ?

Comment: is there any reason as to why you aren't using simple url                                   url: 'localhost/test.php',

Comment: It's not listed in your code example, but to see that warning you must be using `async: false`. If so, remove it. It's bad practice anyway.

Comment: Sorry guys i forgot to add, but when i try with async: false i still got the same error...

Comment: A side note: the `url` should be `url: location.hash.replace('#', '')`, because `location.hash` returns the hash with the hash symbol **#**