# Ajax controls have stopped working when user control loaded asynchronously and multiple times by JQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, httphandler

I have created a user control which has several ajax controls. I am using this user control under `datalist` itemtemplate and binding it for each item of datalist, till now every thing working fine as I am loading the user control from server side, but using this approach page takes a lot of time to render as user control is loading one by one and the data calculation under user control itself takes time.

Then I tried to load the each user control asynchronously using `jQuery`, `Ajax` and `IHttpHandler` but `AjaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender` stopped working. But If I load the user control by server every thing works fine.

to load it by server just uncomment this `<%--<uc:CountryInfo runat="server" ID="ucCountryInfo" /> --%>` line in **AsyncLoadDemo.aspx** file and comment this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "renderUC" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "CountryID").ToString(), js, True)
```

line in **AsyncLoadDemo.aspx.vb** file

Below is the code that I have created to demonstrate the issue.

**AsyncLoadDemo.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .floating {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .vertical-text {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: center center 0;
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 4px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function LoadControl(countryID, parentDivID) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'UserControlHandler.ashx?CountryID=' + countryID,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#' + parentDivID).html(response);
                $('#' + parentDivID).show();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });

        //return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <CompositeScript>
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
            </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetail" runat="server">

        <asp:DataList ID="dtLstCountry" runat="server" DataKeyField="CountryID" ShowHeader="False" RepeatColumns="3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="opacity: 1;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; height: 200px; opacity: 1; padding: 3px; padding-left: 6px; border: none" runat="server" id="tdExpandCollaps">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgRatingInfoVerticalTag" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" ImageUrl="~/Left-Slider-open.png" />
                            <div class="vertical-text" style="width: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                                <%#Eval("Country")%>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlRatingInfo" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlRatingInfo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <div id="divDynamicControl" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; width: 98%; overflow: hidden;">
                                            Loadidng control ..
                                            <%--<uc:CountryInfo runat="server" ID="ucCountryInfo" /> --%>
                                        </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <AjaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeRatingInfo" runat="Server" SkinID="skinVerticalCollapsiblePanelExtender"
                    TargetControlID="pnlRatingInfo" ExpandControlID="imgRatingInfoVerticalTag"
                    CollapseControlID="imgRatingInfoVerticalTag" Collapsed="False"
                    CollapsedText="cls" ExpandDirection="Horizontal"
                    ExpandedText="exp" ScrollContents="false" SuppressPostBack="true"
                    EnableViewState="True"
                    AutoCollapse="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:DataList>

    </asp:Panel>


    <AjaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cp1" runat="Server"
        TargetControlID="pnlDetail" ExpandControlID="pnlHeader" CollapseControlID="pnlHeader"
        TextLabelID="lblSearch" ImageControlID="imgVerticalTag" ExpandedText="Search Users (Hide Details...)"
        CollapsedText="Search Users (Show Details...)" EnableViewState="true" SuppressPostBack="true" ExpandDirection="Horizontal" />

</form>
```

**AsyncLoadDemo.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class AsyncLoadDemo
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindCountryDataList()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BindCountryDataList()

    Dim dtblCountry As DataTable = GetData()
    dtLstCountry.DataSource = dtblCountry
    dtLstCountry.DataBind()

End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim dttblResult As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow

    dttblResult.Columns.Add("CountryID", GetType(Int32))
    dttblResult.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))

    dr = dttblResult.NewRow()
    dr(0) = 1
    dr(1) = "INDIA"
    dttblResult.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dttblResult.NewRow()
    dr(0) = 2
    dr(1) = "USA"
    dttblResult.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dttblResult.NewRow()
    dr(0) = 3
    dr(1) = "UK"
    dttblResult.Rows.Add(dr)

    Return dttblResult

End Function

Protected Sub dtLstCountry_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dtLstCountry.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim parentControlID As HtmlControl
        parentControlID = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("divDynamicControl"), HtmlControl)

        Dim js As String = String.Format("LoadControl({0},'{1}');", DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "CountryID"), parentControlID.ClientID)

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "renderUC" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "CountryID").ToString(), js, True)

    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

**CountryInfo.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="CountryInfo.ascx.vb" Inherits="CountryInfo" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxToolkit" %>

<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid darkblue;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 100%; background-color: lightblue; color: white">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlStateHeader" runat="server">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style="cursor: hand">
                    <td align="left" width="5%">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLocationVerticalTag" ImageUrl="~/VerticalTag.gif" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="95%">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlStateCollaspseText">
                            <b>State Info</b>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlStateCollaspsePanel" runat="server">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="40%">State Name:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="60%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStateName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">State Population:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPopulation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<AjaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeLocationInfo" runat="Server"
TargetControlID="pnlStateCollaspsePanel" ExpandControlID="pnlStateHeader"
CollapseControlID="pnlStateHeader" Collapsed="False" TextLabelID="pnlStateCollaspseText"
CollapsedText="State Info (Show Details...)" ExpandDirection="Vertical"
ExpandedText="State Info (Hide Details...)" ScrollContents="false" SuppressPostBack="true"
EnableViewState="True" ImageControlID="imgLocationVerticalTag"
AutoCollapse="False" />

<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid darkblue; margin-top: 20px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 100%; background-color: lightblue; color: white">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmploymentInfo" runat="server">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style="cursor: hand">
                    <td align="left" width="5%">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEmployment" ImageUrl="~/VerticalTag.gif" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="95%">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEmplopyementCollaspseText">
                            <b>Employment Info</b>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmploymentCollaspsePanel" runat="server">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">Employment Number:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="50%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmploymentNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">UnEmployment Number:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnEmploymentNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<AjaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpEmploymentInfo" runat="Server"
TargetControlID="pnlEmploymentCollaspsePanel" ExpandControlID="pnlEmploymentInfo"
CollapseControlID="pnlEmploymentInfo" Collapsed="False" TextLabelID="pnlEmplopyementCollaspseText"
CollapsedText="Employment Info (Show Details...)" ExpandDirection="Vertical"
ExpandedText="Employment Info (Hide Details...)" ScrollContents="false" SuppressPostBack="true"
EnableViewState="True" ImageControlID="imgLocationVerticalTag"
AutoCollapse="False" />
```

**CountryInfo.ascx.vb**

```
Partial Class CountryInfo
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Private _countryID As Integer
Public Property CountryID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _countryID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _countryID = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub
End Class
```

**UserControlHandler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="UserControlHandler" %>
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class UserControlHandler
Implements IHttpHandler
Implements IReadOnlySessionState

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return True
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    If (context.Request("CountryID") IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim countryID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request("CountryID"))

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        context.Response.Write(LoadUserControl(countryID, context))
    End If

End Sub

Protected Shared Function LoadUserControl(countryID As Integer, context As HttpContext) As String

    Using dummyPage As New Page()

        Dim dummyForm As New HtmlForm()

        Dim htmlHeader As HtmlHead = New HtmlHead("runat='server'")
        dummyPage.Controls.Add(htmlHeader)
        Dim scriptMgr As New ScriptManager()

        Dim dynnamicUC As UserControl = DirectCast(dummyPage.LoadControl("~/CountryInfo.ascx"), UserControl)

        SetUserControlParameter(dynnamicUC,countryID)
        dynnamicUC.ID = "ucCountryDetails_" + countryID.ToString()
        Using writer As New StringWriter(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            dummyForm.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptMgr)
            dummyForm.Controls.Add(dynnamicUC)
            dummyPage.Controls.Add(dummyForm)
            Try
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(dummyPage, writer, False)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try

            Return writer.ToString()
        End Using
    End Using

End Function

Private Shared Sub SetUserControlParameter(ByRef uc As UserControl, countryID As Integer)
    Dim ucType As Type = uc.GetType()

    Dim propCountryID As PropertyInfo = ucType.GetProperty("CountryID", BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    Try
        propCountryID.SetValue(uc, countryID, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

This is the javascript warning I am receiving

1. Warning

   > Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
   >   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
   >   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
   >   A.removeChild(B)}}}A.insertBefore(B,A.firstChild);return v}var
   >   E=false,w=e.xhr();if(w){e.username?w.open(m,e.url,e.async,e.username,e.password):w.open(m,e.url,e.async);try{if(e.data||a&&a.contentType)w.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",e.contentType);if(e.ifModified){c.lastModified[e.url]&&w.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since",c.lastModified[e.url]);c.etag[e.url]&&w.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match",c.etag[e.url])}s||w.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");w.setRequestHeader("Accept",
2. Error

   > Uncaught Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object
   >   of type 'Sys.Extended.UI.Animation.LengthAnimation' cannot be
   >   converted to type 'Sys.Extended.UI.Animation.PropertyAnimation'.
   >   Parameter name: instance

Please help me to fix this issue...

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis: I have updated the post please check.. I am not getting how to fix this javascript issue.

Comment: Any body have any idea to fix the problem

Comment: For the javascript warning please review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
        <compilation batch="false" debug="false">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          </assemblies>
          <expressionBuilders>
            <remove expressionPrefix="Resources" />
            <add expressionPrefix="Resources" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPResourceExpressionBuilder, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
         <add expressionPrefix="SPHtmlEncodedResources" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPHtmlEncodedResourceExpressionBuilder, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <add expressionPrefix="SPSimpleFormattingEncodedResources" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleFormattingEncodedResourceExpressionBuilder, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <add expressionPrefix="SPUrl" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.SPUrlExpressionBuilder, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          </expressionBuilders>
        </compilation>
```

Comment: I will defiantly try it, currently I am out of office, tomorrow I will replay you

Comment: Did you try this code ever in ASP.net? if yes then can you please post here for my reference