# XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated in My Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

i have problem with my Ajax request.

when i am login with Ajax request it's like /Employee/Login with POST to controller it's working fine.

but return response is JSON type and not properly redirect to home page.

here is my Ajax Function

function Login() {

```
ShowProgressImage();

// var parameteres = $("#frmAdminLogin").serialize();

var parameteres = {
    "UserName": $("#UserName").val(),
    "Password": $("#Password").val(),
    "RememberMe": $("#RememberMe").is(":checked")
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/Employee/Login/",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "objAdminLoginViewModel": parameteres }),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.ResponseCode == 1) {
            window.location = "/Product/Index/?filterby=recent";
        }
        HideProgressImage();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        HideProgressImage();
    }
    //complete: function () {
    //    window.location.href = "/Product/Index/?filterby=recent";
    //}
});
```

}

i have attached error image below

[Click Here to Show error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P5BU.jpg)

So please suggest me actually where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this warning, do **not** use:

**async: false**

in any of your $.ajax() calls. This is the only feature of XMLHttpRequest that's deprecated.

The default is async: true, so if you never use this option at all, your code should be safe if the feature is ever really removed (it probably won't be -- it may be removed from the standards, but I'll bet browsers will continue to support it for many years).

Comment: i am not using async:false in my ajax call

Comment: that is the default property of ajax call

Comment: try to use this   $.ajax({
        url : endpoint,
        type : "post",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seems to be causing the warning, becuse there is not a async: false sentence.

and actually the line :

```
window.location = "/Product/Index/?filterby=recent"
```

it does not match the url in the image. "localhost:5435"
Maybe you are omitting the code that actually causes the warning

in fact the code that is causing the warning is using the option "XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials" another reason to believe that is not the code that you're showing.

Comment: before it's going to window.location = "/Product/Index/?filterby=recent" this line it's show JSON data on screen

Comment: and XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials ?

Comment: mmm. maybe adding asyc: true, but documentation says that "true" is the default value :/

Comment: your code seems to be correct, are you using additional code that you did not write ?

Comment: what is browserLink.

Comment: i disabled those broswer link from visual studio. Ajax call working fine in Chrome but not working in FireFox. how it strange ?.

Comment: the error in firefox is not clear in the image. :( firefox shows you a description of the error?