# How do static website templating systems get html from a file and insert it into a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a *very* simple templating system for my website. It consists of just loading the header and footer from two files and inserting them into each one, with the jQuery load() function. The XMLHttpRequest that this function relies on is now depreciated, so I was wondering how the major static site generators add HTML content from a file into a specific web page. Could you explain to me the techniques they use?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest deprecated? Since when? The whole modern web is built on this function.

Comment: @GolezTrol It says `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @DanielHarrin You should learn to read the whole sentence... `**Synchronous** XMLHttpRequest` + `Developers must not pass false for the async argument when entry settings object's global object is a Window object.`