# Jquery add active class, Deprecation error?

Tags: jquery

I know this question have been asked alot, but i can't find a fix...

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        target = $('.ActiveMenu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
        $(target).addClass('active');
        console.log(target);
    });
</script>
```

Main.js
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbNzLP

[image]

Comment: The error you got is not related at all to the code you added, it's related to `$.get/$.post/$.ajax`

Comment: the error you are getting is related to get/post/ajax request. not the code you shown

Comment: So what can i do?

Comment: Find the relevant code and fix it? It's kind of like asking "my isn't my whatsapp working?" when you took of the battery from your phone...

Comment: added main.js, is this relevant?

Comment: Are you using visual studio? It seems the error is coming from the BrowserLink tool (the thing that refreshes your styles in browser when you make a change in code without actually refreshing the page). I don't think it's connected to your code.

Comment: Yes i'm using visual studio.

Comment: Well it's not your fault, it's just the way the feature is written (using async: false). You can disable it if you are not using it and don't want to see this message, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32615326/4108884

Comment: Well i disabled BrowserLink, but it didn't add the class?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled BrowserLink and fixed my markup, did the trick. Thanks