# Warning message when trying to add data from Ajax request to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to load data from server to an element with jQuery.get on an element mouseover.
I have this function:

```
$('#myButton').on('mouseover', function() {$.get('/myPage', function(data){$('#elem').html(data)})});
```

The content of /myPage loads but the console returns the following warning:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous Xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end's user experience.

This warning does not appear if I just try to display data in console.

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your environment to see what cause the issue exactly.
You cannot generate synchronous request from jQuery.get() method because it is a wrapper of jQuery.ajax() with default "async" option set to "false"