# ajax not setting value on declared variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with this javascript function. What I'm trying to do is, finding a specific "Material Description" using ajax call. When I try to console.log the ajax function, the data is showed up. But when I'm setting to an array, it won't set the array value and skipped. Using "async: false" give me this warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.

without async will give me undefined result.

```
$('#iBarcode').keypress(function (keyPressed) {
            if (keyPressed.which == 13) {
                var barcode = $('#iBarcode').val()
                var splitted = new Array()
                var arrayCnt = -1;
                for (var i = 0; i < barcode.length; i++) {
                    var flagStart;
                    if (barcode.charAt(i) == ')') {
                        flagStart = true
                        i += 1
                        arrayCnt += 1
                        splitted[arrayCnt] = ''
                    }
                    if (barcode.charAt(i) == ('(')) {
                        flagStart = false
                    }
                    if (flagStart == true) {
                        splitted[arrayCnt] = splitted[arrayCnt] + barcode.charAt(i)
                    }
                }
                console.log(setMatDesc(splitted[0])) //value showed here
                splitted[arrayCnt + 1] = setMatDesc(splitted[0]) //value not showed here and skipped?
                splitted[arrayCnt + 1] = currentDate

                $('#iBarcode').val('').focus
                console.log(splitted)
            }
        })

        function setMatDesc(MatID) {
            var result
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_MatDesc")',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                data: { MatID: MatID },
                success: function (data) {
                    result=data
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })

            return result
        }
```

I would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try `async: true`?

Comment: yes, it's not working

Comment: u should understand how async request work, when u call setMatDesc(splitted[0]), and ajax will be triggered, but main thread will not wait for ajax complete, so your splitted[arrayCnt + 1] = setMatDesc(splitted[0]) will not work, because value haven't come back, u can take a look about promise for javascript.

Comment: Related: "[jQuery has deprecated synchronous XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest)." Then, "[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)" and/or "[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a call back function which will get executed after ajax call completes like:

```
function setMatDesc(MatID, calback) {
        var result
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Get_MatDesc")',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: { MatID: MatID },
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data); // note this
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
}
```

and at calling end do like:

```
setMatDesc(splitted[0],function(result) {

    splitted = result;
    splitted[arrayCnt + 1];
    splitted[arrayCnt + 1] = currentDate;

});
```

The code might not work as i have not tested but this is the way to return the data from a function doing ajax call as the ajax call executes asynchronously and the function executes the body before the ajax call completes back from the server.

Comment: still learning about this async thing. is it possible without async: false?

Comment: this will work with `async:true`

Comment: hmm true, but it only show using alert(result). using the result to assign variable not working

Comment: i have to add "await" after setMatDesc(), and its working with async: true