# Error jquery Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in Modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a function to Edit fields of the MVC table bootstrap.
But it gives me an error everytime i use thi function.

```
<script>
    function createOrEdit(id) {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        var EditUrl = '@Url.Action("CreateOrEdit")' + '/' + id;
        $("#modalCreateOrEditContent").load(EditUrl, function () {
            $("#modalCreateOrEdit").modal({
                keyboard: false
            }, 'show');
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and the error is:

jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

How to solve it?

Comment: You are getting error or warning?

Comment: A warning! But when i do deploy to the server test, the modal does not work so i think it could be the problem @RajeshB

Comment: Then follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest

Comment: I hope above link will solve your issues.

Comment: let us know which you one you tried and solved the issue.