# How to handle Ajax that return Html that includes essential <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I encounter an Ajax scenario and seeking for suggestions/improvements. My current implementation works fine but I think there might be a better approach from experienced developers who ever deal with similar problems.

**The below code are pseudo for laying out the problem**

main.html

```
<button id="mBtn" data-target="#modal"></button>
<div id="modalC"><div class="modalContent"></div></div>
```

modalContent.html

```
<script src="script_1"/>
<script src="script_2"/>
<script src="script_3"/>
<section> Something here </section>
```

**Those `<script/>`s are essential for elements inside `<section>` to function properly and must be executed after `<section />` is ready**

main.js

```
$(".mBtn").click(function(e) {
    $('#modalC').modal('toggle');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: /modalContent.html,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $(".modalContent").empty().html(response);
        },
        error: function (response) { }
     });
});
```

The above code is my current approach. The logic is

Click button -> trig modal -> call ajax -> load html to modal.

`Jquery Ajax` handle `<script/>` in `modalC.html` synchronously (which is what I want). As a result, I got the following warning

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

I try to get rid of the warning with another approach. So my another potential approach is to put those `<script/>` into `main.html` and then enforce reloading them every time by appending a `?rnd=rando_mnumber` to scripts when I trig the modal, but I worried it may cause other problems if I don't handle pre-existing scripts properly. Any Suggestions or other approaches?

Comment: What about the scripts is unique for each ajax call?  I'm trying to understand why you need to reload them for every ajax call.

Comment: @Taplar the reason is because there are variable, etc. in those `<script>` that is initial based on the new modal content. So when new ajax is called, the old `<script> ` must be reload as well for correct functionality.

Comment: I guess that is just warning to not make sync call on the main thread. Are you sure that jquery ajax is making async calls (I am not sure.). may be that `$.ajax` is making sync request that will blocking state to main thread.

Comment: So thinking about the concept of `function(){}`'s.  How hard would it be to write that script logic so that, with each ajax call you make, you then call a function, giving it the dynamic parts that it needs to operate, so that the script is only loaded once.

Comment: @AneesIjaz the warning is expected behavior. You might want to checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest. One of answer specifically mentions that behavior,  But again, if possible, sometimes you just want to get rid of it.

Comment: @Taplar Good point about the `js` part, I haven't thought a lot about it but I will take a look on it. I believe it's far more complex than what you thought. Those scripts involve complex logics. Dynamic and static variable from initialization, etc. Rewriting may causes  issues and requires a lot of efforts (not all scripts are created by me but I know how to change them. there are legacy code, script from other libs). I have to analyst it first to see if it's worth for scalability. That's why I used pseudo code. Anyway Thx.

Answer (score 0):

What i do to load script from an ajax request is to append script to body.
i do this :

```
$('#my-container-div script').appendTo('body');
```

but the best thing to do, when no library change and only params change, is to pass the params:

```
<div class="container-child" data-model='{"value": "New", "name": "something"}'></div>

//(in the callback)
var model = $('#my-container-div .container-child').data('model'); //json is parsed automatically
model.value == "New";//true
```

with this aproch, you can set async to true and get your script working.